# Azure function app failed to deployment because of spacy-transformer module

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

torch is not installing and getting failed and I need that module so is there any option to get it done with requirement.txt

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Torch is not installing and getting failed, and I need that module so is there any option to get it done with requirement.txt:

This seems to be an issue with [oryx build](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx) releases and that is why deployment patch is failing with an error oryx deployment files doesn't exists and unable to fetch the logs also.

***After I've done a workaround,***

To avoid this, I added [ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD = false](https://www.blimped.nl/fixing-azure-webapp-zip-deployment-issue/) in `function app->Configuration-> Application Settings` (App that will deploy my function) Portal as shown:

[image]

After doing it, I've installed `torch & torchvision` modules with the compatible versions by using:

```bash
pip install torch===1.8.0 torchvision===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

**Note**: If the provided `torch & torch_vision` versions are not compatible then it throws an error asking us to check the dependencies to avoid conflicts.

[image]

*And*

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

***requirements.txt:***

```py
azure-functions==1.12.0 //Give latest version
requests==2.28.1
torch==1.8.0
torchvision==0.9.0 
typing_extensions==4.4.0
```

Sometimes `requirements.txt` file will not get properly configured.
To avoid that, Freeze the requirements by using terminal:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

I created an Azure function with python runtime stack, it worked for me and ***deployment got succeeded:***

[image]

***Triggered successfully after deployment and function app is running***:

[image]

***Verification in Azure Portal:***

[image]

***Version_check***:

**Python_Version**:  `Python 3.9.3` (taken)

Upgrade `pip` to the latest version if prompted.

**PyTorch**: [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/)

*Restart the Visual Studio code* (`ctrl + shift + p`) *by viewing `command palette -> Reload the window and clear cache` to avoid module conflicts if needed.*

Comment: I followed the process the requirement file not getting installed and also HTTP trigger link does not appear when the deployment gets completed . I will just see the file coping in the terminal

Comment: Did you give a try to add any manually?

Comment: can we install manually that module in azure function apps

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `torch` module while deploying with oryx build. I suggest you create a function app in portal with `Python` runtime stack. Now install required packages inside the function itself.